# "(firstName.toLowerCase()).charAt(0)" in this manner with Java? the charAt() method should only work with a string reference variables?

Tags: java, string, reference, charat

```
String firstName, middleName, lastName; 
char firstInitial, middleInitial, lastInitial;

firstName = "Huckle";
middleName = "Berry";
lastName = "Fin";

firstInitial= (firstName.toLowerCase()).charAt(0);
middleInitial = middleName.charAt(0);
lastInitial = lastName.charAt(0);

System.out.print(firstInitial);
System.out.print(middleInitial);
System.out.println(lastInitial);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: why is it possible to chain these methods. toLowerCase() and charAt() methods together? the return types are literals not reference variables is that correct. the format is stringReference/object.method(). Just confused why this works is all and it does work.

Comment: Note: `Character.toLowerCase(firstName.charAt(0))` is more efficient.

Comment: " the return types are literals" Return values are never *literals*. They are just references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *...why is it possible to chain these methods. toLowerCase() and charAt() methods together?...*

String class is immutable in java, so calling `toLowerCase()`  will return another string with the result of that operation

> *..the charAt() method should only work with a string reference variables?...*

you can use a literal string as well

```
firstInitial = "Huckle".toLowerCase().charAt(0);
middleInitial = middleName.charAt(0);
lastInitial = "Fin".charAt(0);
```

but as I said before, the method tolowerCase can be invoked on string objects and will return another string

you can (even that is not making much sense) call a sequence of method together

like:

```
firstInitial = firstName
        .toLowerCase()
        .toUpperCase()
        .substring(0)
        .toLowerCase()
        .toUpperCase()
        .trim()
        .charAt(0);
```

Comment: Wow! my book never told me that.  thanks for your time and answer.